# Prevent backspace from moving up the directory tree in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Whenever I press backspace in nautilus, it seems to move up the directory tree. This is really annoying, especially when I am using the search feature and hold backspace to delete whatever I entered into the search bar. In the few milliseconds between when I fully delete whatever is in the search bar and when I release the backspace button, nautilus goes 4-5 folders up the directory tree.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, keyboard shortcuts in many GTK applications cannot (anymore) be easily customized, although it could probably be done with python extensions.

I can reproduce the behavior you describe. Indeed, it is fully buggy. Even when the search field is not yet completely cleared, nautilus may already move up a directoy. Expected behavior would be that Backspace only deletes characters as long as the search field remains in focus.

While you do not mention the Ubuntu version, this behavior is observed in Files 42 in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. This keybinding is not anymore used in later versions to move up the directory tree.